# How to take picture snapshot from button Click and upload as Attachment

Tags: visualforce, integration, button

I want to take the snap from the button Click(Take Picture). 
When I open the account, "take snap" button should appear on top and if we click that button, the web cam or phone cam turn on. after capturing the pic, it should upload to attachment.

Can you anyone give me the suggestion?

Comment: Please add any code you already have developed, or add detail so a single question can be answered. No one on this site will write all of this code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **photobooth.js** jQuery library which uses the HTML5 api to access the webcam to capture the images. It is available on [github](https://github.com/WolframHempel/photobooth-js) The author has also provided a detailed [documentation](http://wolframhempel.github.com/photobooth-js/) on the usage.

I was working on Proof of Concept for face recognition in Salesforce and that is when I had embedded photobooth.js in one of my visualforce pages. It can even capture pictures from a mobile device when this page is accessed via google chrome on a phone.

More details regarding the usage with code samples could be found on this [blog](http://sfdc-gyaan.rhcloud.com/2014/04/face-recognition-in-salesforce-using-html5-webcam-and-mashape/)

Comment: Bhat, is this work for mobile camera as well?

Comment: Yes works for mobile camera as well but only when the URL of the application is accessed via chrome browser (or probably any other browser which supports HTML5) doesn't work when accessed via SF1 app.

Comment: I would like to put one button in account and camera should open when i clicks. how to implement this. i saw your blog but you are integration the mashap. Is this needed?

Comment: Nope, in your use case you just need to make use of the photobooth.js library. The blog is only for reference (using photobooth.js in visualforce page). I know there is some additional stuff of face recognition using mashape but you can just ignore that.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will try. I need your assistance in future :).

Comment: How to get the image after click the snap. I want to get the image and add in the attachment. Can you guide?